# Needed help in UINavigationController in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar

I am learning iPhone since i am new bee and wanted to implement something like the following please guide me:

Actually what i want is that i have a navigation controller with 3 screen
1st Screen: Having a button to got Next Screen
2nd Screen: Having some images and Button to upload them onto some web portal and a button to go to next screen
3rd Screen: Having a label Only

Now when i am on 2nd screen i press on Upload Button to upload it onto my web portal it takes about 5-6 minutes depending upon the size of the data. So i want to achieve that i would display a little progress bar on the UINavigation bar and a label which shows me that this much files sent and this much left and i can also goto the next or previous screen using the back button and UIButton on 2nd screen and it keeps on showing me the uploading label and progress bar onto the navigation bar. So please guide me friends how can i achieve this. I have implemented everything regarding uploading and label updating for this much files left and this much files done but what i am not getting is how to add label and progress bar on NAvigation BAr and update it on other screens as well. please guide me. i will be very thankful to you.

I am waiting for some positive responses. Guide me through some code and guidelines and tutorials. i am new bee in iPHone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See ASIHttpRequest library it has some code which you want.

Comment: but i dont needed HttpRequest i said i am done with all uploading process i just needed some way to add UILABEL and Progress bar onto the navigation bar and during downloading i could goto one another screen but the progress bar keeps displaying me the current number of files uploaded.

Comment: i hope you get what i want?? :)

Comment: I have seen this kind of functionality in remail iPhone open source app. You can get the functionality from there. the code is available on google svn.

Comment: the same functionality you are talking about it displays downloading of mails in a progress bar and also it is updating label it is showing this in toolbar but you can add that to navigationBar's titleView